# C# WCF Repositories

Tags: c#, wcf

I've in my Data Layer several REPOSITORY Classes that perform CRUD operations to the DB. I'm not sure about this design since that most of the tables will need a dedicated class per Repository and after a while I'll end up with a lot of REPOSITORIES for each table that exists in the DB. I did this because, of course, I`m still learning C# and because every sample that I see in the Web, a dedicated REPOSITORY per Table is needed, so... I did the same... 
(If better options exists, please let me know)

Any way, I`m also learning WCF and from what I have seen so far appears that the implementation design is somewhat similar to repositories in the DataLayer.
In WCF I have an Interface ServiceContract that is implemented by the other Class that exposes those operations.

Here`s my confusion with this, the WCF ProxyClient will use the Operations defined in the ServiceContract to perform calls to the DB, but since that I want to expose the same CRUD operations to remote WCF clients, should I create one class per each Table as I have in the Data Layer REPOSITORIES?

From several examples that saw online, the WCF ServiceContract is more likely to be used for specific Operations, like GetSomething by ID, performThis or That... But those operations are more likely to be performed by the Presentation Layer and Business Layer... And If I use WCF to Communicate Between Business Layer and Data Layer, should I expose CRUD operations in WCF service to proxy clients?

I`m sorry for the long description, but my head is spinning...
Perhaps with your help I can make any sense of all of this...

Comment: Why do you want to use wcf to communicate between business and data layers?

Comment: It is not clear how you integrate all the stuff. Could you provide some example of your repository interface, service contract and how they intend to communicate?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must think in WCF as framework to expose some of your business logic (from msdn):

> Service operations enable you to expose business logic in a data service

Then, when you say:

> And If I use WCF to Communicate Between Business Layer and Data Layer

That does not make much sense in the most of cases, the best approach is:
Service Layer (WCF) > Business Layer > Data Access Layer.

Here is a good example of this from msdn:

[image]

Since you must think in "what" you really want to expose, your code must follow this idea. So, for instance, you have a repository called "Client" that has a couple of methods for CRUD, and some repositories related to "Client" like "ClientType" and "ClientExtraData".

Your service don't need to have the same structure, you can encapsulate all in a "ClientService", that has some operations like "GetClient", "GetFullClient" that returns Client and ClientExtraData, and so on. This is just an example to clarify what I mean.

Same approach as MVC here, your Model for your user interface does not to be same Model from your repository.

Create a service model and use Request and Response patterns in your service.
You can read more about here: http://www.servicedesignpatterns.com/requestandresponsemanagement/datatransferobject

And here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658090.aspx

Hope this can help you design and writting your service layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using azure table storage as your table, you can have a single generic repository with a type constraint to implement ITableEntity interface.

Your repository can then internally convert the input entity into a DynamicTableEntity and write it to azure table storage. You can decide which table the entity needs to be written based on entity type or a custom entity property like a domain name etc..

For WCF service contract it is slightly more complex. WCF supports serialization over inheritance. You can have your ServiceContract take a common base class in its Operation Contracts as parameter and/or return value. Then you need to define the actual child classes (the entity classes) via KnownTypeAttribute in your WCF Service Contract explicitly so you can use it to pass your entities back and forth.

This way your architecture will have a common repository for multiple entity types and a common WCF ServiceContract.